# iOS 8 keyboard greyed out after app returns from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, background, keyboard

In my app when home button is pressed and later the app is put back to the foreground, there is always grey box instead of the system keyboard. No matter what UITextField is pressed, this grey box always appear until the app is killed and started again.

Before entering background, `[UITextFiled resignFirstResponder]` is called for every UITextField.

I have also tried some other solutions like:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.window endEditing:YES];
}
```

The issue is present even if no resigning is done, simply every entering to background will break the keyboard.

The grey area do not react on touches, all touch events are sent to views below, like there was no grey box at all.

On iOS7, there is no problem. Could it be some iOS system bug? 
Thanks for help.

Example screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpVMr.png

Comment: Were you able to know why this is happening? I am seeing similar behavior when the app is in the split screen view.